# Error Call to a member function attach() on null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship

I want to create tag system but I have an error "Error
Call to a member function attach() on null ". Look at my code

***Relationship:***

**Job.php**

```
public function services(){
        $this->belongsToMany('App\Jobervices');
    }
```

**Jobservices.php**

```
public function jobs(){
    $this->belongsToMany('App\Job');
}
```

And I created pivot table

```
Schema::create('job_jobservices', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->integer('job_id');
    $table->integer('jobservices_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

***Controller and view***

Into controller I tryed attached my services. Look at this.

```
$job = Job::create([
           'title'          => $request->title,
           'description'     => $request->description,
           //...
        ]);
$job->services()->attach($request->services);
```

I think, $request->services is good becouse If i try dd($request->services), it display me
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vexu.png) but just in case I'll show you my view

```
<select class="js-example-responsive col-12" multiple="multiple" name="services[]">
    @foreach($services as $service)
        <option value={{ $service->id }}>{{ $service->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
    @error('services')
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        {{ $message}}
        </div>
    @enderror
```

I don't know why but it display me an error

> Error Call to a member function attach() on null

Do you know what is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should return with the relationship.

```php
public function services()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Jobervices');
}
```

```php
public function jobs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Job');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on **laravel 7**  even I return with the relationship from model but nothing worked. Actually it was not error in code, finally I fixed it with :

```
composer update
composer dump-autoload
```

After this everything worked fine.

**Model code**

```php
public function adjustments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'adjustments')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
```